# how to detect webview or browser in android

Tags: javascript, php, android, css, webview

I'm going to detect webview or browser in android
I want to display a banner in Android browsers. Which users click to install app. And I do not want to display this banner on the webview android.

I use this:

```
    <?php
     if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "app.mypackage") {
      echo 'WebView'; }
      else {
     echo 'no-WebView';
     }
   ?>
```

But that does not work, and displays the 'webview' in browser and webview app

There is another way to do this?

Comment: let me give you a little hint from the end-user perspective: **don't** - i *hate* websites that display a huge banner for their app, blocking a lot of content and requiring pixel-precise tapping skills. just mention the app somewhere on the landing page and be done with it - if i cared about having the app installed, i'd have the app installed.

Comment: I just want to put a small banner from the Landing page (donwload app) link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not accurate but you could use Javascript to check the platform that the site is running on using:

```
navigator.platform
```

Possible result(s) of using this property will include:

- HP-UX
- Linux i686
- Linux armv7l (Android)
- Mac68K
- MacPPC
- MacIntel
- SunOS
- Win16
- Win32
- WinCE

Comment: How can I use this to display a banner (just) in (Android browsers)?